# Сократить немного код

Tags: java, android, инспекция-кода

Можно ли как-то преобразовать в более короткое решение?
Как-то по-хитрому вынести в метод?

```
btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class));
    }
});

btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Подключите либу [Retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda). Так вы сможете писать код в стиле 8 явы. Ваш код превратится в это:

```
btnSignup.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class)));

btnReset.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class)));
```

Comment: :( почему моя АIDE эти лямбды не распознает?

Comment: @Flippy, а  Retrolambda подключена?

Comment: Как её в AIDE сунуть?

Comment: @Flippy, а эта IDE использует gradle? Если да - то по ссылке на гитХабе в ридми всё написано. Если нет - боюсь что никак - это плагин для градла

Comment: Использует, но не как студия. На enSO уже нашёл, нет поддержки. Ну что ж, буду отсталым.

Comment: @Flippy, попробуйте писать на полноценном компе) На планшете же неудобно)

Comment: До сих пор не могу свыкнуться - много кнопок, глаза бегают, не в своей тарелке. Не в планшете, а в телефоне.

Comment: @Flippy, блин, да у вас, должно быть, офигенная сила воли - кодить на телефоне)

Comment: @Flippy думаю, этот комментарий будет удалён, ибо это всё же перебор.

Answer (score 6):

Есть предложение вынести создание `Listener'а` в отдельный метод, например

```
private View.OnClickListener getListener(Class<? extends Activity> activityType){
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, activityType));
        }
    };
}
```

Тогда ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
btnReset.setOnClickListener(getListener(ForgotPasswordActivity.class));
btnReset.setOnClickListener(getListener(SignUpActivity.class));
```

Comment: Кривая реализация моего ответа?

Comment: @Flippy я не знаю, что вы хотели описать в своем ответе, в андройде мало что смыслю. Тут напрашивается, вынос дублирующего кода в отдельный метод.

Comment: @Flippy в этом ответе разметка в XML никоим образом не используется, так что это уже определённо не "как в вашем ответе". К сожалению, не очень разбираюсь в терминологии паттернов, но это что-то вроде фабрики `Listener`-ов получается.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov а для чего используется `Class<?>` вместо `Class`? Вроде же разницы никакой.

Comment: @Regent Ни для чего, это всего лишь, привычка - использование дженериков там где они есть.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov думаю, для проверки что передаётся `Activity`, а не что-то "левое", можно написать `Class<? extends Activity>`. И generics останутся, и смысл в них будет.

Comment: @Regent если это будет работать, то можно подкорректировать. Повторюсь, под андройд никогда не писал.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший ответ, примерно такое я и пытался реализовать с выносом метода, но всё же ответ Юрия более компактный, тем более я так раз таки использую Java 1,8 в проекте.

Answer (score 1):

Если кнопка ничего больше не умеет, кроме как переходить в активность, то лучше в `xml` дать ей `onClick`, а в активности реализовать соответствующие методы, а вообще вы можете создать метод.

```
private void goTo(Class c) {
startActivity(new Intent(context, c));
}
```

И вызывать его из слушателей кнопок, передавая класс активности "куда"

```
goTo(SignUpActivity.class);
goTo(ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
```

Comment: Назначение слушателей клика в разметке - зло)